# How to save JSON data from Google Developer Tools?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Using the "inspect" feature, the network resources that a certain website was using.  Here it's just an interactive real-time bus map.

I added just one filter, the string `vehicle` and filter narrows down to requests to `service-status.js` being made on 30 second intervals each file is `2.5kB` and `102ms` which was the time for the request to happen.  Finally, it says `32kB / 1.9 MB transferred`.

How do `*.json` files or a transcript of the exchanges listed here?  There is a `HAR` file option, which saves extra information.  Using the search filter, I only need a fraction of the network resources being transferred.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try webQsee (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webqsee-web-sniffer-recor/gamdpfnfkjknkimfbboonmgdfnondfme?hl=de), it offers a lot of filtering and export options. So you can not only export to HAR format but also to Excel.